# Iterating through an array of character strings that also contains unused elements

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, initialization, c-strings

Problem: I want to print only the three elements defined in the array **names** without changing my defined array size. This program currently prints out the three elements, but also prints out seventeen new lines as it iterates through all 20 elements.

Question: How and where do I create a condition that breaks out of the loop when it checks for an element that doesn't have a value with at least one character? In other words, how do I not print out the extra seventeen lines?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_I 20
#define MAX_J 20

int main() {
    char names[MAX_I][MAX_J] = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

    // First example
    printf("Example 1:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_I; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_J; j++) {
            printf("%c", names[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Second example
    printf("\nExample 2:\n");
    for (char* iter : names) {
        printf("%s\n", iter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C++

Comment: @Slava [Yes, it is](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1f9d5ef54bb75f4).

Comment: You check if a `char c` is zero by `c == 0`. You should do this right before you would print it.

Comment: Try using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An empty C-string has its first (and only!) element set to `'\0'` (aka `0`).

Your array declaration will be zero-initialising your remaining elements, so you can rely on this rule.

Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_I 20
#define MAX_J 20

int main() {
    char names[MAX_I][MAX_J] = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

    // First example
    printf("Example 1:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_I; i++) {

        // *** This block is new ***
        if (names[i][0] == '\0')
        {
           // Empty string! Skip this, and all following
           break;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_J; j++) {

            // *** This block is new ***
            if (names[i][j] == '\0')
            {
               // End of string!
               break;
            }

            printf("%c", names[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Second example
    printf("\nExample 2:\n");
    for (char* iter : names) {

        // *** This block is new ***
        if (iter[0] == '\0')
        {
           // Empty string! Skip this, and all following
           break;
        }

        printf("%s\n", iter);
    }
}
```

Notice I also took the liberty to skip printing trailing nulls, in your first example.

Comment: @downvoter: a reason for downvoting would help a lot.

Comment: opinion: checking empty strings / end of strings in the for loop condition like `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_I && names[i][0] != '\0'; i++)` could be leaner.

Comment: In the first example, you should get rid of the inner loop entirely, just use `printf("%s", names[i])` instead, like the second example uses. That would make much more sense than looping through the individual characters printing them one at a time and looking for a null terminator manually: `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_I && names[i][0] != '\0'; i++) { printf("%s\n", names[i]); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Absolutely the program can be further improved; I am only adding the requested semantics. OP can fiddle with the layout to their heart's content ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each element (one-dimensional array of the type `char[MAX_I]`) of the two-dimensional array

```
char names[MAX_I][MAX_J] = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
```

that was not explicitly initialized is implicitly initialized like

```
{ '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' }
```

where the number pf zeroes is equal to `MAX_I`. So, in fact, non-explicitly initialized elements contain empty c-strings.

So a loop that outputs explicitly initialized elements of the array can look for example the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I && *names[i]; i++ )
{
    std::cout << names[i] << '\n';
}
```

or

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I && names[i][0] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    std::cout << names[i] << '\n';
}
```

Or if it is a C program then

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I && *names[i]; i++ )
{
    puts( names[i] );
}
```

or

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I && names[i][0] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    puts( names[i] )
}
```

If an empty strings can be present among non-empty strings then the loop can look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I; i++ )
{
    if ( *names[i] ) puts( names[i] );
}
```

or

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_I; i++ )
{
    if ( names[i][0] != '\0' ) puts( names[i] );
}
```

Or if to use the range-based for loop then like it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_I   20
#define MAX_J   20

int main() 
{

    char names[MAX_I][MAX_J] = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

    for ( const char *s : names )
    {
        if ( *s ) std::cout << s << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```